# Why did Harry Potter become a more powerful wizard than Hermione, given that she was a better student and learnt faster than Harry?

Tags: harry-potter, wizards, hermione-granger

As a young student in Hogwarts, Hermione learnt much faster than Harry. She also was more hardworking. Any teacher would have placed a bet on Hermione on becoming a better wizard given her brilliance and diligence.

How did Harry become a more powerful wizard than Hermione later, given that he faced Voldemort, survived and even defeated him later? I doubt Hermione could have survived an encounter with Voldermort.

Comment: On what scale are you grading wizards so that Harry is the 'more powerful' of the two? Hermione is usually considered better at most magic than him, except for in DADA where even she admits he's better than she is. In the final encounter with Voldy he's already fought in a few direct confrontations with him and been in far more dangerous situations than Hermione had. He's the only one to come out of OotP battle unscathed of the 6 students that went in, he went to the Cave in HBP, fought Voldy in GoF (nevermind all the tasks). Experience is a great teacher.

Comment: Also many more experienced and skilled Wizards and Witches than Harry or Hermione died at Voldy's hands, Harry won through luck, figuring out the wands, and trusting his friends - not brute strength.

Comment: yes, anytime Harry squared up w/ Voldemort, he [Harry] escaped or won because he had wand lore on his side or Dumbeldore (OotP). Harry never just out and out defeated Voldemort on equal footing.

Comment: Hermione might have had a higher intelligence stat than Harry, but Harry had a MUCH higher charisma stat which often beats out intelligence, especially when applied to the titular character of the series.

Comment: "[**If Harry had a magic duel with Hermione, who would win?** *Very good question! Because until about halfway through Azkaban, Hermione would have won. But Harry - without anyone really noticing it - is becoming exceptionally good at Defence Against the Dark Arts. So that's the one area in which, almost instinctively, he is particularly talented. Apart from Quidditch.*](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2000/0700-swns-alfie.htm)"

Comment: What do you mean by powerful? Hermione can make better potions, better at transfiguration, charms, and many more. Harry is better at DADA and broom flying. Even Neville is better at Herbology than both of them. Everyone is powerful in their own terms. It is purely opinion base on what type of magic you consider more powerful or important.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are both powerful wizards, but both differs in some ways. Hermione is a brilliant witch, and as Hagrid says in book 1:

> “An’ they haven’t invented a spell our Hermione can’ do”

...which is true. She's so young and has already learnt all spells and books by heart. Plus given the fact that she's a *Muggle-born*, which means everything she did on Hogwarts on their first day are her firsts too.

Meanwhile, Harry, who is also a not a *Muggle-born*, but was raised by Muggles and does not learn all the spells and books by heart. He's no better than Hermione when it comes to exams, but he defeated the Dark Lord. Which makes you wonder how come Harry is a more powerful wizard than Hermione?

You need to understand that Harry is meant to deal with the Dark Lord, and Hermione isn't. I bet that if Harry died, Hermione would still be able to survive, and might even defeat the Dark Lord, because she is a one excellent witch! But hey, let us never forget that Harry won't be able to survive all throughout until the end without the aid of Hermione and Ron, we all know that.

*Remember when they went to the forest to hide? Hermione's the one who performed the charm to protect them.*

*She remembered that the Devil's Snare is afraid of light on Philosopher's Stone.*

*She solved the logic of the potions made by Snape on Book 1.*

*She created a PERFECT Polyjuice Potion, **AND IT'S HER FIRST TIME DOING IT**.*

We could go on a very long list on how many times Hermione saved *that powerful wizard* who defeated the Dark Lord. She's not the one who defeated Voldemort, but the long list will prove how great and excellent she is.

And by the way, I have no idea on the measurement of who's greater than who. It's like comparing Dumbledore and Voldemort. Voldemort is a great wizard, but did bad things. While Dumbledore is, too, but did not go on the Dark side. But they say (and I believe because it's what I want to believe) that Dumbledore is much greater that Voldemort, for he is the only one Voldemort is afraid of.

It's who you want to believe that is more powerful. But that would only be our opinions or views.

Comment: Actually, Harry is not muggle-born! His mother was, but his father came from a wizarding-family.

Comment: Oh yes, thanks for correcting me. What I mean is that he was raised by Muggles. Thanks again! :)

Comment: You could say that Hermione is smart, but Harry is street smart - to phrase it crudely.